# In Linq to XML, how to you get ALL descendents of root?

Tags: linq, svg, linq-to-xml

In Linq to XML, how to you get **ALL** descendents of the root?

I can't get my statement to even compile as it always says

> A query body must end with a select clause or group clause

So given this XML (SVG in this case):

[image]

I would like to enumerate all the shape nodes (rect/ellipse/path etc):

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\diagram.svg");

var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants().SelectMany(); // <- doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to add `select c` linq expression instead of the `.Select()` or `.SelectMany()` function call:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\diagram.svg");

var query = from c in xml.Root.Elements()
            select c;

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    // do work 
}
```

Also in my case I need `.Elements()` of root rather than `.Descendents()` as the latter flattens the tree structure of the SVG which is probably not what most people want when parsing the SVG. So  the `Elements()` gives you all the immediate children of the root element.

Comment: Note that the pattern `from x in expr select x` is exactly the same as `expr`. The LINQ is just wasting time and code in most cases. You could just do `foreach (var element in xml.Root.Elements())`